# Serial port acting weird after hibernate/resume?

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

Guys I am having a weird problem with my vb.net application after the computer goes into hibernate mode and resumes. Before it goes into sleep mode I close all my serial ports and set it to nothing...

```
Private Sub SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PowerModeChangedEventArgs)
    oEventLog.WriteEntry("Power change detected: " & e.Mode.ToString)
    txtStatus.AppendText("Power change detected: " & e.Mode.ToString & vbCrLf)
    If e.Mode <> PowerModes.Resume Then

        Try
            If Input IsNot Nothing Then
                Input.Dispose()
                Input.Close()
                Input = Nothing
            End If

            If Output IsNot Nothing Then
                Output.Dispose()
                Output.Close()
                Output = Nothing
            End If
        Catch
            txtStatus.AppendText(Err.Description)
        End Try


    Else
        initilizeSerialPorts()
    End If

End Sub
```

When the computer resumes I initialize my serial ports again. The problem is when I try to open them again it says they are already in use. So I loaded up process explorer to see what has it open and it's still my application! So it seems closing them and setting them to nothing does nothing. If I close my application and re-run it everything works just fine.

```
Private Function initilizeSerialPorts() As Boolean

    If Input IsNot Nothing Then
        Input.Dispose()
        Input.Close()
        Input = Nothing
    End If

    If Output IsNot Nothing Then
        Output.Dispose()
        Output.Close()
        Output = Nothing
    End If

    Input = New SerialPort(cmboInput.SelectedItem.ToString)
    Output = New SerialPort(cmboOutput.SelectedItem.ToString, Input.BaudRate, Input.Parity, Input.DataBits, Input.StopBits)

    Me.Refresh()

****MSGBOX HERE MAKES IT WORK?!!****

    Try
        If Not Input.IsOpen Then
            Input.Open()
        Else
            MsgBox("Unable to open the serial port " & Input.PortName)
            Return False
        End If
    Catch
        MsgBox("Unable to initalize serial port " & Input.PortName & vbCrLf & "Error: " & Err.Number.ToString & " " & Err.Description)
    End Try



    Try
        If Not Output.IsOpen Then
            Output.Open()
        Else
            MsgBox("Unable to open the serial port " & Output.PortName)
            Return False
        End If
    Catch
        MsgBox("Unable to initalize serial port " & Output.PortName & vbCrLf & "Error: " & Err.Number.ToString & " " & Err.Description)
    End Try


    Return True




End Function
```

Ok here is the kicker...if I put a message box before I open my port again it works? No message box and I get a failed to open port message it's in use. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have no idea as to why it behaves that way, but have you tried not bothering to close the serial ports?

Comment: Closing a serial port can easily deadlock if the DataReceived event handler does unwise things like calling ReadLine() or Invoke().  Having to *wait* for several seconds after calling Close() before trying Open() again is a hard requirement.  Just don't do this, it is pointless.